# Can't install Ministro service on Android virtual machine

Tags: android, qt, qt5, ministro

I had asked a similar question [for Necessitas before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728800/qt-necessitas-error-cant-find-ministro-service), but now the solution no longer works for Qt 5.

The problem is similar, when deploying my application on a real phone, Ministro installs fine, but on the Android virtual machine, the Ministro service says:

> Can't find Ministro service. The application can't start.

Here are some screenshots:

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple. There are two ways:

```
adb install Ministro.apk
```

or

```
"Install Ministro from APK" (QtCreator)
```

as per this screenshot:

[image]

See further information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator) or [here](https://files.kde.org/necessitas/installer/test/).

Comment: OK, I installed it using "Install Ministro from APK", but now when I run my application with "Use Ministro service to install Qt", it still says "Can't find Ministro" and fails, when I use "Bundle Qt libraries..." or "Deploy local Qt..." it starts, but the theme is not 'native' - I think it's Plastique, it has black checkboxes. Here's [a screenshot](http://imgur.com/X0X0aDo).

Comment: @sashoalm: are you sure you properly downloaded the latest ministro?

Comment: @sashoalm: have you tried to install Ministro from command line, too?